# opening file in chrome without using full path

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, windows-10

I'm in `Windows 10` opened the terminal from and headed to the same directory where my file `0.png` is saved, and I was able to open it in chrome running the below command:

```sh
start chrome --new-window "file:///C:/Users/hasan.DESKTOP-HU2FQ29/PycharmProjects/rust/0.png" --incognito
```

- Is there a better way (shorter) so I do not need to use/know the full path.
- Is there a way to add another flag to hide/remove title bar from this window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, in windows it is just `cd`, and to get it as variable, it is `%cd%` and in Mac and Linux it it is `pwd`, I run:

```sh
C:\Users\hasan.DESKTOP-HU2FQ29\PycharmProjects\rust>start chrome --new-window --app="file:///%cd%/0.png" --incognito --disable-extensions --window-size="640, 640"
```

and got:

[image]

I think in Mac:

```sh
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --new-window --app="file:///%pwd%/0.png" --incognito --disable-extensions --window-size="640, 640"
```

And in Linux:

```
$ google-chrome --new-window --app="file:///%pwd%/0.png" --incognito --disable-extensions --window-size="640, 640"
```